# Masked text which fills on scroll with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I saw this neat example and I was wondering if its possible to do in javascript/CSS?

Basically I see there's a text with experimental text-stroke CSS property applied, BUT when the user scrolls past it the text has a filled effect, not like filled but more like a css-mask type of effect?

This is what I'm talking about.

https://i.imgur.com/cnvav7m.mp4

How can I achieve this effect? I don't need you to write all the logic I just need someone to explain me how they did this neat effect??

Comment: A common way to fake this is to have two containers with identical content, scrolled simultaneously and fixed in position so the content lines up perfectly, but they can be styled separately.

Answer (score -1):

To do a parallax effect, add these css props into your background image:

```
.my-background {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover
}
```